# Large Data set Macro query & alternative to Vlookup request

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary

This query is two fold. Any assistance would be much appreciated and unfortunately there is a lot of detail behind this so apologies for the great deal of text.

I am working on updating a 12 month trending report that pulls data from one sheet using a series of complex vlookups based on several criteria (Project, unique project id, Order, yr-month etc). Yes it would likely be easier to use pivot tables, but unfortunately because of the way this document is used the people with access to it want it to remain as is, from a format and function perspective but want the document sped up (takes roughly 5 minutes to calculate when ever something is changed.)

The data set is 36 columns by 50000 rows with 7 columns containing identifiers used to pull in specific data on the trending sheet

As it current sits on a monthly basis new data (approximately 6000 rows) of additional data is added.

I've added two macros to the document in an attempt to reduce user error

I am currently using the following code to take the order number remove the duplicates and then apply an index/match to pull in the relevant Project and then use countif to apply a unique key to the end of the project (using concatenate)

```
Sub ProjTrending1()

Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet

'Defines S1 as a Worksheet
Set s1 = Sheets("All Data")

'Defines S2 as WorkSheet
Set s2 = Sheets("Workings")

'Defines LastR1
Dim LastR1 As Long, DataRange1 As Range

'Finds last row cell working sheet
LastR1 = s2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

'Takes Data from Order Column of defined data Sheet and copy & pastes it to Working Sheet Column B
s1.Range("J1:J" & LastR2).Copy s2.Range("A1")

'Removes Duplicates from Column B Working sheet
s2.Range("A2:A" & LastR1).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlNo

'Copies the formula from B2 and applies it to all cells in column B where column A has values
s2.Range("B2").Copy s2.Range("B2:B" & LastR1)

'Copies the formula from C2 and applies it to all cells in column C where column A has values
s2.Range("C2").Copy s2.Range("C2:C" & LastR1)

End Sub
```

The formula is column B is as follows

```
=INDEX('All Data'!E:E,MATCH(Workings!A2,'All Data'!J:J,0))
```

The formula in column C is as follows

```
=B2&COUNTIFS($B$2:B2,B2)
```

The data set in worksheet All Data is approx 50k rows long and will continue to grow. The issue I'm not running into is that this macro is starting to take a great deal of time to run because the information in column C is used as a unique identifier on the trending report.

Is this because I have a vast number of Vlookups on the trending tab (approx 20k) pulling data based on this or is there an issue with the macro I have created to create a unique identifier?

I've been looking at alternative ways in which I could draw the data through to the trending tab (dictionaries etc) with no luck so far. It would be much appreciated if someone could offer an alternative to 20k vlookups.

Comment: It would be helpful to see more details about how your using `VLOOKUP`. Some common tricks for speeding up calcs are to turn off display updates and calcs at the beginning of the macro, then turn them back on at the end. Also, some of your formulas access an entire column (e.g., `'All Data'!E:E`); if you only access the range with data that may help speed things up.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I didnt know application.screenupdating = false until you mentioned it so thanks for that. This shaved 30 seconds off a 27 minute macro run time. I've narrowed the issues down to the remove duplicates element. When running this over 50k lines of data it just cant cope. I'm looking towards learning how to do this via a dictionary object.